# Replace section on string in java

Tags: java, string, replace

I have this section of code

```
String string = "somestring";
String str2 = "str";
String str3 = "xxx"

if ( string.match("(.*)" + str2 + "(.*)") ) {
 // 
}
```

result = somxxxing

how can i replace that section of string with str3?
i need this to work for every strings

Comment: Why on earth are you not using `String::replace()`?

Comment: I'm out of votes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702357/how-to-replace-a-substring-of-a-string

Answer (score 2):

Check out the javadoc for [java.lang.String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

You're probably looking for [`String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), which replaces every occurrence of target with replacement.

e.g.

```
result = string.replace(str2, str3);
```

Comment: Oops, my bad. Edited.