# Java Substring Replacement: How to replace 2018 with 2014 in this code?

Tags: java, string, xpath, replace, substring

I wish to get 2018 replaced with 2014. Posting Year, which is currently having the 4/5/2018, must be changed to the purchase date of 4/5/2014 !! Please review the code:

```
String PostingPeriodIs=  Jan 2014
String PostingPeriod=  05/04/2018

int lnthPostingPeriodIs = PostingPeriodIs.length();
int lnthPostingPeriod = PostingPeriod.length();
String Year=null , YearIs=null;
try {
    Year= PostingPeriodIs.substring(lnthPostingPeriodIs-4);
    YearIs=PostingPeriod.substring(lnthPostingPeriod-4);
    System.out.println("Year is =========>"+Year);
    System.out.println("Expected year is ==>"+YearIs);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Exception in catchMethod");
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
String PostingYear= PostingPeriod.replace(Year, YearIs); 

uiDriver.webUIDriver.webDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='trandate']")).sendKeys(PostingYear);
```

Comment: Maybe something like this: `String PostingPeriod =  "05/04/2018".replace("2018", PostingPeriodIs.split("\\s+")[1]);`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace a substring of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702357/how-to-replace-a-substring-of-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here,

```
String PostingYear= PostingPeriod.replace(Year, YearIs);
```

> .replace(toReplace,replacedWith)

Just interchange like below,

```
String PostingYear= PostingPeriod.replace(YearIs, Year);
```

Hope this helps