# Android: Start a new line in a string after full stop in java

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code to try and start a new line after the end of a sentence, so for example "2.Put the turkey" would start a new line. But this doesn't happen. What have I done wrong?

"1.To make the Mexican seasoning, mix the ingredients together in a bowl. 2.Put the turkey mince and Mexican seasoning into a large bowl and mix well with your hands. 3.Heat half the olive oil in a frying pan over a high heat and cook the onions, spring onions and peppers for 3 minutes. Add a pinch of salt and pepper. Remove the vegetables from the pan and set aside.

```
    method.replaceAll("\\.\\s?", "\\.\n");
    methodText = findViewById(R.id.methodText);
    methodText.setText(method);
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, so `replaceAll` **returns** the new string: `method = method.replaceAll("\\.\\s?", ".\n");`

Comment: Duplicate of [How to replace a substring of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16702357/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
String method="1.To make the Mexican seasoning, mix the ingredients together in a bowl. 2.Put the turkey mince and Mexican seasoning into a large bowl and mix well with your hands. 3.Heat half the olive oil in a frying pan over a high heat and cook the onions, spring onions and peppers for 3 minutes. Add a pinch of salt and pepper. Remove the vegetables from the pan and set aside.";
        String m=method.replaceAll("\\. ", ".\n");
```